# $scope.path not working when click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm trying to make the path change when I click a btn but, it doesn't work .

I tried the [**paths-ajax-load-example**](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/blob/master/examples/0302-paths-ajax-load-example.html) but could't make it work.

Im not sure if it's a problem with the lib

html code

```
<body ng-controller="HomeCtrl"> 
    <nav id="search">
        <form ng-submit="getPath()" class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
            <input class="form" type="text" ng-model="origin" name="origin" placeholder="Origin">
            </br>
            <input class="form" type="text" ng-model="destination" name="destination" placeholder="Destination">
            </br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Find path</button>
        </form>
    </nav>
    <leaflet paths="path" defaults="defaults" width="100%" height="100%"  markers="markers" center="center"></leaflet>
</body>
```

Angular controller

```
angular.module('demoapp')

.controller("HomeCtrl", [ '$scope',  function($scope) {

    $scope.getPath = function() {

        angular.extend($scope, {
                center: {
                lat: 4.5656,
                lng: -74.09266,
                zoom: 12,
            }
        })

        $scope.path = {
                polyline: {
                    type: "polyline",
                    color: 'black',
                    weight: 5,
                    stroke: "true",
                    latlngs: [{lat: 4.5656, lng: -74.09266}, {lat: 4.56588, lng: -74.09306}]
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}]);
```

app.js

```
angular.module('demoapp', ['leaflet-directive', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngMessages', 'ngRoute', 'mgcrea.ngStrap'])
  .config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      })
      .when('/:map', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
  }]);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you show code that declares demoapp module?

Comment: Added @MaximKuzmin

Comment: @SebastianSalamanca: where is your function which is not working?

Comment: @Thalaivar getPath() on the controller. When i click the map should update the path. right now is not doing anything.